# Is it possible to cut short evaluation of a higher-level function?

Tags: swift, sequence

I am looking for a way to stop a higher-level function after evaluating part of its input sequence.

Consider a situation when you look for the first index in a sequence that satisfies a certain condition. For example, let's say we are looking for the first position in an array `a` of `Int`s where the sum of two consecutive values is above 100.

You can do it with a loop, like this:

```
func firstAbove100(a:[Int]) -> Int? {
    if a.count < 2 {
        return nil
    }
    for i in 0..<a.count-1 {
        if a[i]+a[i+1] > 100 {
            return i
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

The looping stops as soon as the position of interest is discovered.

We can rewrite this code using `reduce` as follows:

```
func firstAbove100(a:[Int]) -> Int? {
    if a.count < 2 {
        return nil
    }
    return (0..<a.count-1).reduce(nil) { prev, i in
        prev ?? (a[i]+a[i+1] > 100 ? i : nil)
    }
}
```

However, the disadvantage of this approach is that `reduce` goes all the way up to `a.count-2` even if it finds a match at the very first index. The result is going to be the same, but it would be nice to cut the unnecessary work.

Is there a way to make `reduce` stop trying further matches, or perhaps a different function that lets you stop after finding the first match?

Comment: @paulvs Because it's copy-paste gone wrong :-) Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's any built-in way to do that with `reduce`. The entire point of `reduce` is that it combines and evaluates the *entire* sequence. For this specific use case, you would probably need to write your own function, like you did in your first code block.

Comment: `reduce` is a just a `forEach` that is passing a value to the next iteration. If you want short-circuiting, you have to use a high order function that supports it. Or write your own version of `reduce`. In this case I think that using `reduce` is a very bad choice because you are not actually using the accumulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already said, `reduce` is specifically designed in order to evaluate an entire sequence and therefore not designed to short-circuit. Using it in this way to find an the index of an element that meets a given predicate is best done with `indexOf` as [@Casey says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37416020/2976878).

Also as of Swift 3, there is now a `first(where:)` function on `Sequence` that allows you to find the first element that satisfies a given predicate. This could be an even more suitable alternative than `indexOf`, as it returns the element instead of the index (although in your particular example these are the same).

You could write your example like this:

```
func firstAbove100(_ a:[Int]) -> Int? {
    guard a.count > 1 else {return nil}

    return (0..<a.count-1).first { i in
        a[i]+a[i+1] > 100
    }
}
```

However if you want a more general high level function that will iterate through a sequence and break out if it finds a non-nil result of a given predicate – you could always write your own `find` function:

```
extension SequenceType {

    func find<T>(@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> T?) rethrows -> T? {
        for element in self {
            if let c = try predicate(element) {return c}
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

You could now write your `firstAbove100` function like this:

```
func firstAbove100(a:[Int]) -> Int? {
    if a.count < 2 {
        return nil
    }
    return (0..<a.count-1).find { i in
        a[i]+a[i+1] > 100 ? i : nil
    }
}
```

and it will now short-circuit when it finds a pair of elements that add to above 100.

Or let's say instead of returning the index of the first pair of elements in your array that add to greater than 100, you now want to return the sum of the elements. You could now write it like this:

```
func sumOfFirstAbove100(a:[Int]) -> Int? {
    guard a.count > 1 else {return nil}
    return (0..<a.count-1).find { i in
        let sum = a[i]+a[i+1]
        return sum > 100 ? sum : nil
    }
}
```

```
let a = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
print(sumOfFirstAbove100(a)) // prints: Optional(110)
```

The `find` function will iterate through the array, applying the predicate to each element (in this case the indices of your array). If the predicate returns `nil`, then it will carry on iterating. If the predicate returns non-nil, then it will return that result and stop iterating.

Answer (score 4):

`indexOf` will stop after it finds the first match so you might rewrite `firstAbove100` to something like this:

```
func firstAbove100(a:[Int]) -> Int? {
    return a.count > 1 ? (a.startIndex..<a.endIndex-1).indexOf({ a[$0] + a[$0 + 1] > 100 }) : nil
}
```